# Variable type in visual studio code (python)

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am currently using visual studio code for python coding and my past coding experience mainly uses Microsoft visual studio 2019 for c# coding. I notice the 2 IDE are rather similar but I have a problem reading other people's code when the variable type is not known. My question is if there exists a way/extension to know the variable type or must I look through the code to find the variable type.

The first image shows an example of variable type "Any" and I believe the second + third image pretty much shows everything about the class used in the first image but I still don't get what "images" & "img" variables are

[image: Variable type "Any"]

[image: ImageDataset class]

[image: looping through ImageDataset class for images, I have no idea what variable images is as well =.='']

Comment: Python is a dynamically typed language, so you can't be sure of the type until runtime.

Comment: If it quacks like a Duck it might be a Duck

Comment: you can add type hints in python 3.6/3.7, this is just for the reader not for the interpreter/compiler, the linter might use it too

Comment: why post images of source code, just use copy/paste - a lot simpler than images, VSC IS NOT an IDE